# How to make "filledcurves" change color when two or more meet? (GNUPlot)

Tags: colors, gnuplot, transparency

I have created a graph that uses `lines` for the average of my data and `filledcurves` for the error (average-error, average+error). My problem is that the last `filledcurves` that is plotted, covers all other fills, even though I have set its transparency. I want to change this so that when two or more `filledcurves` meet the color is changed and thus the errors are clearly shown for all lines.
My script is:

```
set datafile separator whitespace

set style line 1 lc rgb '#aa5500' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1 
set style line 2 lc rgb '#55aaff' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1       
set style line 3 lc rgb '#aa557f' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1        
set style line 4 lc rgb '#55007f' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1 
set style line 5 lc rgb '#005500' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1 
set style line 6 lc rgb '#0055ff' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 1 
set tics nomirror
set tics front
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid front ls 12

set output 'network_utilization_servers_3_2.png'
set terminal png size 1000,800
set style fill transparent solid 0.25
set style fill noborder
set xrange[0:77]
set yrange[0:1500]
set xlabel "Time (seconds)" font ",12"
set ylabel "Incoming Traffic (KB/s)" font ",12"
set title "Network Utilization in the Servers" font "Helvetica,16"
set key box title "Server" width 10

plot for [i=0:|Group|-1] $Data3 u ($2-6):($3-$4):($3+$4) index i with filledcurves ls i+1 notitle, \
    for [i=0:|Group|-1] $Data3 u ($2-6):3:4 index i w lines ti sprintf("%g",Group[i+1]) ls i+1
```

and my pragh:
[image]

My goal is something like this:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: According to the `help png` you have to specify `truecolor` to use transparency with the `png` terminal. You could also try the alternative `pngcairo` terminal if available.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, though I remember that I had already added this to my script. Oh, well...